# Match two equal fields of arrays of same documents without $unwind

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have below `workouts` collection

```
[
  {
    "receiverWorkout": {
      "exercises": [
        { "_id": "1", "reps": 0 },
        { "_id": "2", "reps": 4 }
      ]
    },
    "senderWorkout": {
      "exercises": [
        { "_id": "2", "reps": 12 },
        { "_id": "1", "reps": 8 }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I need to match same `_id` from `receiverWorkout` and `senderWorkout` exercises and want to add a key `won` **true** or **false** whose `reps` are greater.

If you can see first element of `receiverWorkout` exercises(`{ "_id": "1", "reps": 0 }`) is matching with the second element of the `senderWorkout` exercises(`{ "_id": "1", "reps": 8 }`) because both have same `_id`

Expected output should be something like

```
[
  {
    "receiverWorkout": {
      "exercises": [
        { "_id": "1", "reps": 0, "won": false },
        { "_id": "2", "reps": 4, "won": false }
      ]
    },
    "senderWorkout": {
      "exercises": [
        { "_id": "2", "reps": 12, "won": true },
        { "_id": "1", "reps": 8, "won": true }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I want to avoid `$unwind`

**Please help!!!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation.

Single Pass

```
db.colname.aggregate([
 {"$project":{
  "exercises":{
   "$reduce":{
    "input":"$receiverWorkout.exercises",
    "initialValue":{"receiverWorkout":[],"senderWorkout":[]},
    "in":{"$let":{
     "vars":{
      "sen":{"$arrayElemAt":["$senderWorkout.exercises",{"$indexOfArray":["$senderWorkout.exercises._id","$$this._id"]}]}
     },
     "in":{
      "receiverWorkout":{
       "$concatArrays":[
        "$$value.receiverWorkout",
        [{"_id":"$$this._id","reps":"$$this.reps","won":{"$gt":["$$this.reps","$$sen.reps"]}}]
       ]
      },
      "senderWorkout":{
       "$concatArrays":[
        "$$value.senderWorkout",
        [{"_id":"$$sen._id","reps":"$$sen.reps","won":{"$gt":["$$sen.reps","$$this.reps"]}}]
       ]
      }
     }
    }}
   }
  }
 }},
 {"$project":{
  "receiverWorkout.exercises":"$exercises.receiverWorkout",
  "senderWorkout.exercises":"$exercises.senderWorkout"
 }}
])
```

Without using `$unwind`

```
db.colname.aggregate(
{"$project":{
  "receiverWorkout.exercises":{
    "$map":{
      "input":"$receiverWorkout.exercises",
      "in":{
        "$let":{
          "vars":{"sen":{"$arrayElemAt":["$senderWorkout.exercises",{"$indexOfArray":["$senderWorkout.exercises._id","$$this._id"]}]}},
          "in":{
            "_id":"$$this._id",
            "reps":"$$this.reps",
            "won":{"$gt":["$$this.reps","$$sen.reps"]}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "senderWorkout.exercises":{
    "$map":{
      "input":"$senderWorkout.exercises",
      "in":{
        "$let":{
          "vars":{"rec":{"$arrayElemAt":["$receiverWorkout.exercises",{"$indexOfArray":["$receiverWorkout.exercises._id","$$this._id"]}]}},
          "in":{
            "_id":"$$this._id",
            "reps":"$$this.reps",
            "won":{"$gt":["$$this.reps","$$rec.reps"]}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}})
```

With `$unwind`

```
db.colname.aggregate([
  {"$unwind":"$senderWorkout.exercises"},
  {"$unwind":"$receiverWorkout.exercises"},
  {"$sort":{"receiverWorkout.exercises._id":1,"senderWorkout.exercises._id":1}},
  {"$addFields":{
    "receiverWorkout.exercises.won":{
      "$cond":[
        {"$gt":["$receiverWorkout.exercises.reps","$senderWorkout.exercises.reps"]},
        true,
        false
      ]
    },
    "senderWorkout.exercises.won":{
      "$cond":[
        {"$gt":["$receiverWorkout.exercises.reps","$senderWorkout.exercises.reps"]},
        false,
        true
      ]
    }
  }},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":"$_id",
    "receiverWorkout":{"$addToSet":"$receiverWorkout.exercises"},
    "senderWorkout":{"$addToSet":"$senderWorkout.exercises"}
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thank you very much veeram it gives me the result I wanted.  but I don't want to use `$unwind` here. Sorry I didn't mention this in question.

Comment: Np. I've added an alternative without using unwind.

Comment: This is just amazing. Thanks aaaaaaaa lot veeram. I will surely offer you. Let's see if you someone has even more tricks.

Comment: Np. Let me know what part is not working. Try the updated query as well.

Comment: I've added another query where we create both arrays in one pass.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use array index to achieve this. If I good understand, you need to know, for each entry in your senderWorkout.exercises array, if an element with the same _id is present in receiverWorkout.exercises array. Here's the way to do this :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      "senderWorkout.exercises": {
        $map: {
          input: "$senderWorkout.exercises",
          as: "ex",
          in: {
            $cond: {
              if: {
                $in: [
                  "$$ex._id",
                  "$receiverWorkout.exercises._id"
                ]
              },
              then: {
                _id: "$$ex._id",
                reps: "$$ex.reps",
                result: true
              },
              else: {
                _id: "$$ex._id",
                reps: "$$ex.reps",
                result: false
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

you can try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JFmFmg8mujF)

Comment: Not working because it is giving `true` and `false` for both the  `senderWorkout` exercises. But `senderWorkout` has won both the `exercises` because it has higher `reps`. Please have a look again

Comment: @DarkKnight actually it seems to be working, is just a different id.. in the example.

Comment: No it is just adding true and false to the exercises. I want to add true false to that exercises having greater `reps`.